# How Do I Set Up Visual Studio 2015 with SDL2 For Android, iOS, and Windows Development?

Tags: android, c++, ios, visual-studio-2015, sdl

Visual Studio 2015 has integrated Android Emulator support.  They even have a pre-made template to set up Windows Phone, Android, and iOS targets.  It seems like there should be some way of setting up SDL 2.0 in the same solution to easily toggle between Android and Windows.  I am really hoping for an existing template which includes SDL 2.0, or a tutorial on the subject.

Where am I at right now?  I have a working code base which I've been maintaining in visual studio 2015 based on SDL 2.0, Quite some time back I ported it to Xcode on my mac manually and I was able to run in the emulator.  I have not run on Android yet.  The port in xcode has likely gone stale though as I've updated multiple libraries and it was three years ago.

My ideal answer to this question would result in a working Visual Studio 2015 project with SDL 2.0 configured for iOS, Android, and Windows.  What I am looking for is a series of steps to create a template project that can be used as a starting point to get an OpenGL context initialized via SDL on Windows or the Android emulator.

This might be asking a lot, but I'm hoping someone has already done the work and can simply share it with the world here.

Comment: This question is off-topic as it asks for an off-site resource. I cannot flag it because there is an open bounty.

Comment: The question could be re-worded to include the full list of steps to get it working in the answer here on this site.  I *do not care what the format of the answer is* but the end result should be a working setup and it is not off-topic.  It is a valid question of considerable worth to indie developers everywhere.

Comment: Just in case anyone is wondering... [Unjust Bounty About to Be Awarded to Bad Answer](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackoverflow/comments/4cx8gf/unjust_bounty_about_to_be_awarded_to_bad_answer/)

Comment: You'll notice the moderation team agreed as those answers are deleted. @lankymart I posted that when there were like 3 hours left until auto-bounty award after having it flagged for several hours with no action.

Comment: Question asks for answer here.  I see no reason why a description of a toy project setup steps would not be too broad for SO.  Voting to reopen.

Comment: @M2tM I have an answer to this question regarding windows + android. The key is creating two projects. One is an android makefile project, the second is an android basic application. Putting both of them in the same folder, then copying the data from sdl2/android-project to this folder. Also following sdl2/docs/readme.android.

Comment: @akaltar If you answered this with a series of exact steps that would be incredibly valuable! Then all we would need is a set of steps for iOS. I'm going to go ahead and ask this question now, but for Android only.

Comment: @akaltar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42149447/how-do-you-create-sdl2-visual-studio-2015-or-2017-solution-for-windows-and-andro