# How do you create SDL2 Visual Studio 2015 or 2017 Solution For Windows and Android?

Tags: c++, mobile, visual-studio-2015, sdl-2

Visual Studio 2015 has integrated Android Emulator support. They even have a pre-made template to set up Windows Phone, Android, and iOS targets. It seems like there should be some way of setting up SDL 2.0 in the same solution to easily toggle between Android and Windows targets.

A valid answer to this question will simply be a set of steps to set up the targets for an example SDL2 program that compiles and creates a simple OpenGL/ES context rotating cube or similar which will either create a window and run as a windows .exe or execute in the android emulator depending on the target.

Please include all steps in the body of your answer in a numbered bullet list so that it is a complete stand-alone answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For android specific settings. (Setting up makefiles, the AndroidManifest.xml, etc.) refer to `SDL2/docs/readme.android` and general "command line android help" on the internet.

Setting up the VS2015 solution generally goes as follows:

- Create new folder `project`
- Put game source in `project/src`
- Create shared items project in `project/`
- Create an android makefile project into `project/android`
- Create an android basic application(ANT) project into `project/android`
- Copy the contents of `SDL2/android-proj` to `project/android`
- In the solution explorer check "show all files" and "include in project" all files from `SDL2/android-proj` except jni to the basic application project.
- In the references of the basic app project add the makefile project.
- In the references of the makefile project add the shared items project.
- Edit `project/android/jni/src/Android.mk` to compile your files in `projects/src`
- After building the makefile project, add its resulting .so files from `project/android/libs/` to the basic app project.
- Create other project like usual except instead of including source, just include shared items project in references.

Here is where you can find the shared items project:[image]

Comment: I'll be giving this a try and accepting the answer this weekend!

Comment: Could you explain what exactly is a 'shared files project'? // I also notice that there is nothing moved into the makefile project - could you explain, or give reference to what it would then be doing related to sdl?

Comment: @dk123 See my edit. Also: Shared items projects(corrected from shared files) let you share the same set of files between different projects. In this case the makefile project is going to contain all your app source through this shared items project. This shared items project is then also used in the win32 application project you create. You just put it in the references section.